# linear regression using type 2 sum of squares, how to extract slope, intercept, r2 from model output?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am wondering how to extract slope, intercept and R2 from the output of linear regression using type 2 sum of squares?

I know that it is possible to perform "type II" sum of squares using R package **car**. For example,

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                   y = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10.5))
model <- lm(y ~ x, data = df)
anova_result <- car::Anova(model, type="II")
```

It gives an output like with only Sum of Sq, Df and P value
Anova Table (Type II tests), without slope, intercept and r2.

Comment: This is likely a duplicate, but it is a well written question, great job! I think you want `summary(model)`

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for your comments. I am just not sure by using Anova(model, type="II"), I don't the modify object of model. Then when I ran summary(model), it may give the same results of the default type 1 results.

Comment: I think the R2 will be the same no matter what hypothesis test you run... I might be missing something deep here. See `?car::Anova` for details on the `type` argument and how it gives you different hypothesis tests.

Comment: Regarding the different ways of computing the partitioning of the Sums of Squares (not the model parameters, or the overall R2, given by `lm()`) , see this CV post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20455/171222

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the model parameters and overall R2 is using the base function `summary()`. In your case, the slope is around 2.1, the intecept - 0.2, and the multiple R2 is 0.977.

```
> summary(model)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = df)

Residuals:
         1          2          3          4          5 
 1.000e-01  8.285e-17 -1.000e-01 -2.000e-01  2.000e-01 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.20000    0.19149  -1.044    0.373    
x            2.10000    0.05774  36.373 4.57e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.1826 on 3 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9977,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.997 
F-statistic:  1323 on 1 and 3 DF,  p-value: 4.57e-05
```

The package **car** is letting you test different ANOVA hypotheses based on how you partition the total sum of squares, summarized well in this [Cross Validated post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20455/171222).

Note that the F and p-values for the main effect of `x` will be the same with `type = "II"` and `type = "III"` in this case.